# Using coeffRef with const CwiseUnaryView - Failing when multiplying two CWiseUnaryViews

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I'm having some trouble when using `coeffRef()` with a `CWiseUnaryView` function, but only when the function is declared as `const`

Reproducible example:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>

struct dummy_Op {
  EIGEN_EMPTY_STRUCT_CTOR(dummy_Op)
  EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
  EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE const double& 
    operator()(const double &v) const { return v; }
  EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
  EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE double& 
    operator()(double &v) const { return v; }
};

void foo(Eigen::MatrixXd &out)
{
    //Compiles
    Eigen::CwiseUnaryView<dummy_Op, Eigen::MatrixXd> view(out);
    view.coeffRef(0,0);

    //Doesn't Compile
    const Eigen::CwiseUnaryView<dummy_Op, Eigen::MatrixXd> const_view(out);
    const_view.coeffRef(0,0);
}
```

Returns:

```
<source>: In function 'void foo(Eigen::MatrixXd&)':
<source>:21:28: error: passing 'const Eigen::CwiseUnaryView<dummy_Op, 
Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers 
[-fpermissive]

     const_view.coeffRef(0,0);

                            ^

In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/eigen/v3.3.4/Eigen/Core:413,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/eigen/v3.3.4/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:340:33: note:   
in call to 'Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 1>::Scalar& 
Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 1>::coeffRef(Eigen::Index, Eigen::Index) 
[with Derived = Eigen::CwiseUnaryView<dummy_Op, Eigen::Matrix<double, 
-1, -1> >; Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, 1>::Scalar = double; Eigen::Index = long int]'

     EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Scalar& coeffRef(Index row, Index col)

                                 ^~~~~~~~

Compiler returned: 1
```

Compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/kPHPuC

The side-effect of this, is that the multiplication of two (non-const) CWiseUnaryViews also fails, see example here: https://godbolt.org/z/JYQb3d

Answer (score 2):

The bottom line is that you're calling a non-const method of a constant instance. The (first) `coeffRef` that is being called is the one (and only) in DenseCoeffsBase.h (`DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, WriteAccessors>`), which is not const qualified. The `DenseCoeffsBase<Derived, ReadOnlyAccessors>` class does not have a `coeffRef` method. You can get around this error (and get a warning) if you enable the `-fpermissive` compiler flag.

In the dense case, you probably want to use the `operator()(Index, Index)` method anyway, which does have a const qualified version. I just noticed the [documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseCoeffsBase_3_01Derived_00_01WriteAccessors_01_4.html#adc8286576b31e11f056057be666a0ec8) explicitly says to use that method anyway, even for the non-const version. This is obviously not going to return a const reference, but at least in your example as a double, it shouldn't matter too much.

Comment: The reason why I'm asking about ```coeffRef``` is that it's the source of a compilation error when multiplying two ```CwiseUnaryView``` objects. See here for an example: [https://godbolt.org/z/JYQb3d](https://godbolt.org/z/JYQb3d)

Comment: That's a lot messier. I'd wait for ggael to get back to you. I'd also add that to your question, as that's your actual problem (the internal workings of Eigen are making certain assumptions).

Comment: Thanks for that, will do

Answer (score 2):

`CwiseUnaryView` is intended to be used for L-value like expression, e.g.,

```
MatrixXcd A;
A.real() = something; // `A.real()` is writable
```

If you want to apply an element-wise functor and use it as an R-value, you should use `CwiseUnaryOp` instead:

```
void foo(Eigen::MatrixXd &out)
{
    Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<dummy_Op, Eigen::MatrixXd> view1(out);
    // shorter:
    auto view2 = out.unaryExpr(dummy_Op());

    Eigen::MatrixXd result = view1 * view2;
    // or directly write: out.unaryExpr(dummy_Op()) * out.unaryExpr(dummy_Op());
}
```

Comment: @AndewrJ, What he said ☝. Makes sense, View vs. Op

Comment: Is there any way for the method to be agnostic between R-values and L-values? For example: ```A.real() = A.real() * B.real()```

Comment: @AndrewrJ `A.real()` actually works as R-value as well. I'd need to check where the difference to a custom view is.

Comment: @chtz I've narrowed the problem down a bit further. I'm using the ```CWiseUnaryView``` to return a value from a struct that is pointed to by a second struct. The multiplication works fine if the first struct contains a  declaration for a primitive type (i.e. int/double) as well as the pointer declaration, but fails without it.

See here for an example: [https://godbolt.org/z/7nvhqx](https://godbolt.org/z/7nvhqx)

Comment: It also works with `float` instead of `double`: https://godbolt.org/z/GJUZ41. There seems to be some `sizeof` logic going wrong. Could you report this as a bug to http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/?

Comment: I think I've found the problem. 

```Eigen/src/Core/CWiseUnaryView.h``` L33: ```int(sizeof(typename traits<MatrixType>::Scalar) / sizeof(Scalar))```

Everything compiles after changing this to ```int(sizeof(Scalar))```

Comment: @chtz is this a safe fix to use for now? I'm just waiting on registration before I can report the bug

Comment: @AndrewrJ I'd have to look into it, but on first glance this rather looks like hiding the problem (and could result in regressions in other cases).